# Assign RSHINY text input to a variable for use in a source script

Tags: r, shiny

I have a script that generates a report based on an excel file. I'm trying to wrap it in a SHINY UI so my coworkers will be able to use it, but after hours of research I still can't seem to find how to store text input as a variable that I can use when calling up my report using source(). I know that it stores as input$textinput but I can't use that as my variable in my script. My input is:

```
  textInput("locusinput", h3(strong("Enter Location")), value = ""),
  actionBttn(inputId = "report", label = "Generate Report", style = "gradient", color = "royal", 
  size = "md", block = TRUE),
```

My output is:

```
 observeEvent(input$report, {
          loc <- renderText(input$locusinput, quoted = TRUE)
          output$test <- renderText({paste("<font color = \"#6495ED\"><b>","You have generated a report for ", input$locusinput ,"</b></font>")})

          source("Wastewater_Reporting.R")
```

I've also tried:

```
loc <- input$locusinput
loc <- renderText(input$locusinput)
loc <- isolate(input$locusinput)
source("otherscript.r")
```

and nothing seems to work. (loc is a variable used in otherscript.r) All the documentation I have found has been how to get it to display into the SHINY gui, with nothing about how to use the input as a variable

Comment: You can use `input$locusinput` as a normal variable in shiny with one caveat: it has to be in a **reactive context**, e.g. `observeEvent` or `reactive`. In such a reactive context, you can call your script. For an introduction to shiny's concepts, have a look at https://mastering-shiny.org

Comment: I don't want to change every instance of the variable in "otherscript.r" to input$locusinput. I would like to be able to assign it to the variable used in the other script.

Comment: You can use `loc <- input$locusinput` inside a reactive context

Comment: I updated my code in the question to include the "observe event" I have around it, but I realized I don't have anything saying "reactive" in my code. How do I put it in a reactive context?

Comment: An `observeEvent` is a reactive context, so this is fine. I'm not sure if the scoping works correctly if you use `source("Wastewater_Reporting.R")` within the `observeEvent` (if your script finds the correct `loc` variable), I've never tried it. Could you reformulate the content of "Wastewater_Reporting.R" as a function that takes the `loc` argument as input. Then you could use `source("Wastewater_Reporting.R")` [outside the server function](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson5/) and just call the function in your `observeEvent`

Comment: yeah wrapping your file as a function will be the way to go, for minimal code changes just wrap the whole file in a `make_report <- function(loc){ your file }` and call it inside observeEvent